# Set up Splunk alert based on average of a field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk so pardon me if my question is too naive. I want to set up a Splunk alert if the average of a field is above a threshold. My search is as follows:

```
sourcetype="somesourcetype" search phase | stats avg(f1) as Average
```

If I use

```
sourcetype="somesourcetype" search phase | timechart avg(f1) as Average span=1h
```

I can see the table listing the average of field f1. But with `stats avg(f1)` I do not get anything under statistics panel and I am not sure how to set up an alert if average of f1 is above 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger an alert at a certain threshold, include the threshold in your query then have the alert trigger if the number of results is not zero.

```
sourcetype="somesourcetype" search phase | stats avg(f1) as Average | where Average > 100
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem now is that this field contains the numeric value and "ms". So it looks like in one event I have f1=50ms, and in another I have f1=120ms. How would I modify the query to remove this "ms" when calculating average?

Comment: There are a few ways to do that, but perhaps the easiest is `convert`.  Try `... | convert num(f1) | stats ...`.